# Alterar status DataTables php

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

Tenho uma coluna de atendimento na minha Datatable, onde recebe pendente e concluído. Quero alterar para verde se concluído e vermelho para pendente.

Pesquisei e vi alguns exemplos, sei que tenho que incluir uma classe css para isso...
Segue código:

```js
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="customer_data" class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ide</th>
            <th>terminal</th>
            <th>modelo</th>
            <th>ultima_venda</th>
            <th>sonda</th>
            <th>atendimento</th>
            <th>Detalhes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  <br />
  <br />
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#customer_data').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                    "sProcessing":   "Processando...",
                    "sLengthMenu":   "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "sZeroRecords":  "Não foram encontrados resultados",
                    "sInfo":         "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty":    "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "",
                    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
                    "sSearch":       "Buscar:",
                    "sUrl":          "",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                        "sNext":     "Seguinte",
                        "sLast":     "Último"
                    }
                },
      "ajax": {
        url: "fetch.php",
        type: "POST"
      },
      dom: 'lBfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'copy'
      ],
      "lengthMenu": [
        [25, 50, -1],
        [25, 50, "All"]
      ],
      order: [
        [0, 'DESC']
      ],
      "aoColumnDefs": [{
        type: 'date-uk',
        aTargets: [0]
      }]
    });

  });
</script>
```

Estou adicionando os valores passando pelo um array:

```
$data = array();

foreach($result as $row)
{
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = $row["id"];
$sub_array[] = $row["ide"];
$sub_array[] = $row["terminal"];
$sub_array[] = $row["modelo"];
$sub_array[] = $row["ultima_venda"];
$sub_array[] = $row["sonda"];
$sub_array[] = $row["atendimento"];
$sub_array[] = '<a href="card.php?id='.$row['id'].'"<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Detalhes</button></a>';
$data[] = $sub_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro a parte onde você adiciona valores na tabela. Seu código apenas posiciona como a tabela é iniciada, e nesse caso, não é possível fazer essa lógica.

Desde que você esteja usando PHP em seu código, você poderá fazer uma condição que verifica o valor da linha e já aplica um breve CSS nela antes de ser inserida:

```php
<tr> <!-- /*na coluna de atendimento*/ -->
    <?php
        $class = $atendimento == "concluído" ? "text-success" : "text-danger";
        echo '<td class="' . $class . '">' . htmlspecialchars($atendimento) . '</td>';
    ?>
</tr>
```

No código acima, o operador ternário da variável `$class` irá validar se `$atendimento` é "concluído". Se for verdadeiro, a classe `text-success` será atribuída a ela, se for falso, será `text-danger`.

Além disso, eu entendi que está usando o Twitter Bootstrap no seu código como estilos, então adaptei a resposta para que continue usando as classes do mesmo.

Lembre-se de usar o [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php) para escapar strings que serão escritas dinâmicamente no código.

Comment: Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

$sub_array[] = '<span class="label label-' .($row["status"] == "concluido" ? 'success' : 'danger'). '">' .($row["status"] == "pendente" ? '' : ''). htmlspecialchars($row["status"]).'</span>';

Obrigado pela resposta @CypherPotato.